# Send image with certain parameters?

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have no problem sending plain text.

For example, I have this request:

```
func buyWholeSaler(url : String, token:String, manager:String, fio:String,phone:String, sender:String, carrier:String, document:String,shipping_id:String,pay_type:String, shipping_pay:String, amount_nalogi:String, shipping_return:String,money_recipient :String,comment:String, completion: @escaping (JSON)-> Void) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "shipping_id" : shipping_id,
            "pay_type": pay_type,
            "manager" : manager,
            "fio" : fio,
            "phone" : phone,
            "sender" : sender,
            "carrier" : carrier,
            "document" : document,
            "shipping_pay": shipping_pay,
            "amount_nalogi": amount_nalogi,
            "shipping_return" :shipping_return,
            "money_recipient" : money_recipient,
            "comment" : comment
        ]
        AF.request(url,method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                completion(json)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

But how can I send a picture with these parameters?

I have 2 images

```
var image1 = UIImage()
var image2 = UIImage()
```

How can I rewrite the request in order to send it correctly? For example:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "shipping_id" : shipping_id,
            "pay_type": pay_type,
            ...
            "ur_file_pdv": image1,
            "ur_file_er": image1
        ]
```

I found this request but I cannot understand how it works:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
                        for p in parameters {
                            multiPart.append("\(p.value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: p.key)
                        }
                        multiPart.append(imageVityagPdv.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!, withName: "ur_file_pdv", fileName: "ur_file_pdv.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                        multiPart.append(imageVityag.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!, withName: "ur_file_er", fileName: "ur_file_er.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                    }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
                        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                    }).responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
                        print("upload finished: \(data)")
                        let success = json["success"].stringValue
                    }).response { (response) in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let resut):
                            print("upload success result: \(resut!)")
 case .failure(let err):
                            print("upload err: \(err)")
                        }
                    }
```

It seems to be uploading something to the server but the order does not happen

Comment: What do you mean by "the order does not happen"? The last block of code should work pretty perfectly for what you want to do. You append your parameters and your images (as Data) to the request and then send it as a .post.

Comment: @unixb0y at first case i recieve json response if everything is ok from my server, or some errors, for example empty field. At second case i just recieved `upload success result: \(resut!)`, anything about empty fields,anything from my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add "Data" as a Parameter, especially since a "request" is made to retrieve data from a server and should be pretty small, just giving the server info on what you actually want to receive from it (in textual form). To upload something, you use a POST request which you can do in Alamofire using AF.upload like shown below.

What do you mean by "order does not happen"? Maybe you have some server code so we can see what the issue is? Could be that it wants the parameters as GET, in that case you could add them directly to the URL.

```
func buyWholeSaler(url : String, token: String, manager: String,
    fio: String, phone: String, sender: String, carrier: String,
    document: String, shipping_id: String, pay_type: String,
    shipping_pay: String, amount_nalogi: String,
    shipping_return: String, money_recipient: String, comment:String,
    completion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "shipping_id" : shipping_id,
        "pay_type": pay_type,
        "manager" : manager,
        "fio" : fio,
        "phone" : phone,
        "sender" : sender,
        "carrier" : carrier,
        "document" : document,
        "shipping_pay": shipping_pay,
        "amount_nalogi": amount_nalogi,
        "shipping_return" :shipping_return,
        "money_recipient" : money_recipient,
        "comment" : comment
    ]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        parameters.forEach({ multipartFormData.append("\(p.value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: p.key) })
        multipartFormData.append(image1.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!,
            withName: "ur_file_pdv", fileName: "ur_file_pdv.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        multipartFormData.append(image2.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!,
            withName: "ur_file_er", fileName: "ur_file_er.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    },
    to: url, method: .post, headers : headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value): completion(JSON(value))
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   self.uploadMultipart(buildedWith: { (multipartData) in
        multipartData.append(assestPath, withName: "file", fileName: "mp4", mimeType: "")
```

assest path will be image url, it should be local path, or you can also convert to data form, but this will be better directly append path .